# git conflicts using branches

Tags: php, git, magento

In my project, for example I have two branches(let it be `br_1` and `br_2`). In each branch I make some issues. I have some problems during this:

for some issue (on `br_2`) I need to rename one of the table column. So, everything ok, I made upgrade script(using Magento), it renamed column, works fine. The problem appeared when i switched to another branch.(In this branch my old script was asked to old name of column).

So, now, on br_1 there is an error.

`First way` is to rename table column back, and do what you want on this branch. But after that I need to do it again, and again, before I will merge all branches to master.

`Second way` is to change in the php srcipt on `br_1` the name of old column into the new.

Are there more clean way to resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either [`merge`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html) `br_2` into `br_1`, which will take all the history (commits) in `br_2` missing from `br_1` and merge them on top of `br_1`'s changes.  Or, if your fix in `br_2` is contained in a single commit (like `[548662a4] Fix name of table column`), you can [`cherry-pick`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html) your commit into `br_1`.

First option (takes **all** history from `br_2`):

```
git checkout br_1
git merge br_2
// Potentially fix and merge conflicts, and re-commit
```

Second option (takes a **single** commit from `br_2`):

```
git log br_2
// commit 548662a48154cf741649892cefc421135c65caf1
//   Fix name of table column

git checkout br_1
git cherry-pick 548662a4
// Potentially fix and merge conflicts, and re-commit
```

Comment: Yes, I think about cherry pick, but the problem is that issue with renaming need to be on br_2, and all issues created for br_2, need to be on br_2, but +1 for another way, thanks

Comment: @sergio I am a little confused by why a cherry-pick won't work.  I understand the issue is on `br_2`, but it appears it is also affecting `br_1`.  In that case, I don't see why you wouldn't want the fix in `br_2` to also appear in `br_1`.  If you elaborate, I may still be able to help.